# Calling x text elements from XML

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript-2

I have a flash file which is calling text from XML file in AS2. Here is the XML

```
<goals1>
    <minute>32</minute>
    <name>Name</name>
    <minute>35</minute>
    <name>Name2</name>
</goals1>
```

So this is simple but this code might be bigger or smaller, for example:

```
<minute>32</minute>
<name>Name</name>
```

can be repeated 4 times or more. These are going to be the  minute when the goal is scored and the name of the player and this is going to be listed in the swf, so my question is what to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing XML in AS2 is the most painful thing in the world. Use external library which helps transforming XML in an Object.

The [XMLParser](http://www.greensock.com/xmlparseras2/) from Greensock is quite good.

Once your XML is transfromed into an object you can use standard `for...each` or `for...in` loops.

Regarding your XML: it's not designed properly - the final result shouldn't depend on order of the nodes. I mean:

```
<goals1>
    <minute>32</minute>
    <minute>35</minute>
    <name>Name</name>
    <name>Name2</name>
</goals1>
```

Should, in theory, work in your application, too. But, obviously, it will not. If I were you I would do something like this:

```
<goals1>
    <goal>
        <minute>32</minute>
        <name>Name</name>
    </goal>
    <goal>
        <minute>35</minute>
        <name>Name2</name>
    </goal> 
</goals1>
```

This way, changing the order of the nodes shouldn't break your application.

Comment: I don't have permissions to modify the XML file so I need to do it by the way it is. So maybe if i can select the `<goals1>` tag and from there do something. I'm open for any kind of ideas ?